# How to import large files to google drive from a public google drive shares without downloading?

Tags: google-drive, samsung-galaxy-tab-s-10.5

I need to import [that file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwPIpgeJ2AdnUGUzVGJuak5abDg/) to google drive.

The problem is I can t download it right now, and the file will probably be deleted in few hours as marshmallow for galaxy tab S is out.

Comment: downvotes, why?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Just click on Add to my drive. Download it whenever you are free.

Comment: I only have the download button at the leff of my profile. Even on chrome canary for desktop. What are you using

Comment: Google Chrome, Windows 7. I have logged into my google account

Answer (score 0):

I dont think its possible using the Drive app but. If you are using a browser there is a link [**copy url to google drive**.](http://urltodrive.softgateon.net/) [image: Google drive screen shot]